# npm install polymer-cli fails with error code error code EBADPLATFORM

Tags: npm, polymer, npm-install, polymer-cli

`npm install polymer-cli` fails in my build definition with the following message

> Error: C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd failed with return code: 1\npm.cmd failed with return code: 1

This worked in the last build and there was no file change.

From the log:
2018-02-06T11:00:52.3800853Z [command]C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd install -g bower polymer-cli
2018-02-06T11:00:55.2227287Z npm WARN deprecated bower@1.8.2: ...psst! Your project can stop working at any moment because its dependencies can change. Prevent this by migrating to Yarn: https://bower.io/blog/2017/how-to-migrate-away-from-bower/
2018-02-06T11:01:52.4291618Z C:\NPM\Modules
2018-02-06T11:01:52.4291956Z `-- bower@1.8.2 
2018-02-06T11:01:52.4292118Z 
2018-02-06T11:01:52.4426138Z npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
2018-02-06T11:01:52.4450970Z npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "bower" "polymer-cli"
2018-02-06T11:01:52.4452215Z npm ERR! node v6.9.1
2018-02-06T11:01:52.4454224Z npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
2018-02-06T11:01:52.4454536Z npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
2018-02-06T11:01:52.4454739Z 
2018-02-06T11:01:52.4455469Z npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
2018-02-06T11:01:52.4455849Z npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    darwin
2018-02-06T11:01:52.4456122Z npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
2018-02-06T11:01:52.4456414Z npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   win32

Answer (score 2):

From the logs, you provided it looks like a cache bug, because of some junk that previously exists and that is causing issues.

Open the command prompt with admin privileges and follow the below steps:

1) Clear the cache: `npm cache clean --force`. You can also run npm cache verify.

2) Delete node_modules folder using: `rm -rf node_modules`.

3) Delete any `package-lock.json` file.

4) Remove the `.npm` directory.

5) Remove following directories :

```
   5.1) C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\. 

   5.2) C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache.
```

6) Also, Try by setting environment variables:

`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\nodejs.`

Type in the command line: `which npm`.

Maybe you did not set the system value: `NODE_PATH` it should point to your global module location.

7) Update to the latest `npm` with `npm i -g npm@latest`.

8) Also, Update the latest `node` version.

Hope the above trick resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks, I got this fixed. I had to install the updated version of polymer using install -g polymer-cli@next. That was the problem.

Comment: Thanks..got this resolved by installing latest trial version of polymer

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to ignore optional dependencies during the installation: `npm install --no-optional polymer-cli -g`